# ASP.NET CrystalReportViewer Static Header

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

Does anyone have any ideas on how to add a static header to a Crystal Report displayed in a CrystalReportViewer in an ASP.NET web application?  I need the header labels to stay visible as the user scrolls down through the data in the report.

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do not waste your time in doing research for this. There is no feature in Crystal Reports to support floating header.

Comment: Thanks for the word.  I found this to be the case as well.  Just was wondering if anyone had any ideas.